# How to think asynchronously with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, callback

I just started developing nodejs. I'm confused to use async model. I believe there is a way to turn most of SYNC use cases into ASYNC way. Example, by SYNC, we load some data and wait until it returns then show them to user; by ASYNC, we load data and return, just tell the user data will be presented later. I can understand why ASYNC is used in this scenario.

But here I have a use case. I'm building an web app, allowing user to place a order (buying something). Before saving the order data into db, I want to put some user data together with order data (I'm using document NoSql db by the way). So I think by SYNC, after I get order data, I make a SYNC call to database and wait for its returned user data. After I get returned data, integrate them together and ingest into db.

I think there might be an issue if I make ASYNC call to db to query user data because user data may be returned after I save data to db. And that's not what I want.

So in this case, how can I do this thing ASYNCHRONOUSLY?

Comment: Quite honestly, it's hard to tell what you're really asking.  Since you haven't included any code (even a synchronous version of your code), it almost sounds like you're asking a generic question for us to teach you how to code asynchronously without any details.  That's just not a specific enough question for an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here.  First, if your application already has the user data (the user is already logged in), then this information should be stored in session so you don't have to access the DB.  If you are allowing the user to register at the time of purchase, you would simply want to pass a callback function that handles saving the order into your call that saves the user data.  Without knowing specifically what your code looks like, something like this is what you would be looking for.

```
function saveOrder(userData, orderData, callback) {
  // save the user data to the DB
  db.save(userData, function(rec) {
    // if you need to add the user ID or something to the order...
    orderData.userId = rec.id; // this would be dependent on your DB of choice
    // save the order data to the DB
    db.save(orderData, callback);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sync code goes something like this. step by step - one after other. There can be ifs and loops (for) etc. all of us get it.

```
fetchUserDataFromDB();
integrateOrderDataAndUserData();
updateOrderData();
```

Think of async programming with nodejs as event driven. Like UI programming - code (function) is executed when an event occurs. E.g. On click event - framework calls back registered `clickHandler`.

nodejs async programming can also be thought on these lines. When db query (async) execution completes, your callback is called. When order data is updated, your callback is called. The above code goes something like this:

```
function nodejsOrderHandler(req,res)
{
    var orderData;
    db.queryAsync(..., onqueryasync);
    function onqueryasync(userdata)
    {
        // integrate user data with order data
        db.update(updateParams, onorderudpate);
    }
    function onorderupdate(e, r)
    {
        // handler error
        write response.
    }
}
```

javascript closure provides the way to keep state in variables across functions.

There is certainly much more to async programming and there are helper modules that help with basic constructs like chain, parallel, join etc as you write more involved async code. but this probably gives you a quick idea.